# Locally complete space is topologically equivalent to a complete space

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Can someone please tell me where I can find a citeable reference for the following result:

Call the metric space $(X, d)$ "locally complete" if for every $x \in X$ there a neighbourhood of $x$ which is complete under $d$.

If $(X,d)$ is locally complete and separable then there exists a metric $d'$ on $X$ such that $(X,d) \to (X,d')$ is a homeomorphism and $(X, d')$ is complete.

This result follows immediately from Alexandrov's theorem that a $G_\delta$ subset of a Polish space is Polish, but I'd rather find a statement in the literature of the above more straightforward result if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reference: [this paper](http://www.chimiefs.ulg.ac.be/SRSL/newSRSL/modules/FCKeditor/upload/File/73_1/Bella%20TSIRULNIKOV%20p%209-19.pdf) has a reference [30] that has a proof. The author cites your result and refers to it. I don't have access to these papers, so I cannot verify exactly.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a reference but a short direct proof.

Let $\bar X$ be the completion of $X$. Define $f:X\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=dist(x,\bar X\setminus X)$. Obviously $f$ is continuous, and the local completeness implies that $f$ is strictly positive.

Let $X'\subset X\times\mathbb R$ be the graph of $1/f$. Then $X'$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and complete for the following reason:

If $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X'$, then the first coordinates of $p_n$ are a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Hence they converge to a point of $\bar X$. This point cannot be in $\bar X\setminus X$ because the second coordinates of $p_n$ are bounded.

The metric on $X\times\mathbb R$ can be defined as the sum of two coordinate distances (any other common definition will work too).

Answer (score 5):

The result you want to prove also follows directly from Choquet's characterization of completely metrizable metric spaces as those for which the second player has a winning strategy in the "strong Choquet game". See Kechris, *Classical descriptive set theory*.  The usual proof of this characterization uses Alexandrov's theorem, though, so it may not be what you are looking for.